# sending the content of a txt file as a dm. discord.py

Tags: python, filter, integer, command, discord.py

## hello

I was trying to make my discord bot send something he read out of a txt file to a user as a dm. i have made a command which creates a txt file which should safe some details about the account the user has created. now i want the user to be able to see his account details by sending a command in the discord chat.

#### Imports

```
import discord
from random import *
from time import *
from discord.ext import tasks
from discord.ext import commands
import asyncio
import os.path
```

#### creates file

```
@bot.command()
async def join(ctx):
    if os.path.isfile("{}'s Account.txt".format(ctx.author)):
        em=discord.Embed(title="Fail", description="im sorry, but it seems like you already have an account".format(ctx),color=0x992d22)
        await ctx.author.send(embed=em)
    else:
        em=discord.Embed(title="Welcome", description="You have joined the game.\n send !help to see all the commands.".format(ctx),color=0x2ecc71)
        await ctx.author.send(embed=em)
        open("{}'s Account.txt".format(ctx.author), "w+")
        myFile=open("{}'s Account.txt".format(ctx.author), "a")
        myFile.write("Verified! \n  Coins=0 \n  Attack=0 \n Defense=0 \n")
```

#### should send the user a dm with the account details

```
async def credit(ctx):
    Account=open("{}'s Account.txt".format(ctx.author))
    lines = Account.
    em=discord.Embed(title="Balance", description="")
    em.add_field(name="Coins", value="")
    await ctx.author.send(embed=em)
    "{}'s Account.txt".format(ctx.author.close)
```

#### what im trying to achieve

the command collect should send the user an embed field with 4 more fields in it which should have the titles coins defense and attack. i want the command to read the integers for the respective attributes and then insert them in the field with the respective title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks good!

So I'm assuming the async function `credit` is a command (if not slap a `@bot.command()` in front of it). Then to create a dm with the user, use `channel = await ctx.author.create_dm()` and send like so; `channel.send("Hey bud, sweet dms")`

But you may have already knew that, so onto the good stuff, saving the data from the text file, reading it, and finally putting it into an embed for the user. Firstly, I would save the data like so: `Coins,Attack,Defence`, this way you can easily recover the data without removing clunky words and stuff, because you know that coins will be in the first position, attack will be in the second and defence will be in the third (and so on).

You can then extract the data from the text file like this:

```py
with open(f"{ctx.author}'s Account.txt", "r") as account:
    coins, attack, defence = account.read().split(",")
```

Then send that information to the user's dms, embed if you will:

```py
embed = discord.Embed(title="Account info")
embed.add_field(name="Coins", coins)
embed.add_field(name="Attack", attack)
embed.add_field(name="Defence", defence)
await channel.send(embed=embed)
```

**TIPS**

- When saving the data, I would use the user's id, you wouldn't want two people with the name sharing an account
- In case you don't know, use `w` instead of `r` when saving the users data to the text file